# PHP WHY Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for

Tags: php

```
Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for includes\img\defaultimg.jpg in
```

I read and researched but found nothing useful

in the php manual only says this:

```
If PHP's integer type is only 32 bits on your system, filemtime() will fail on files over 2GB with the warning "stat failed". All stat()-related commands will exhibit the same behavior.
```

but is just a jpg  900k

this is my code works fine in xammp, but not in production

```
  $dirimg="includes/img/";  //this one also throws warning
        $filename = "".$dirimg."".$resultsb['Img'].".jpg";  //the path
        if(file_exists ($filename)){  // exists?
        $timeimg=filemtime($filename);
       $srci="".$dirimg."".$resultsb['Img'].".jpg?=".$timeimg."";   
        }else{$timeimg=filemtime("includes\img\defaultimg.jpg");  //another path, the file does exists
       $srci="includes\img\defaultimg.jpg?=".$timeimg.""; } //
```

both throw the same warning in the respective path,  the file exits btw

the image can be seen, 
but i need to know
when it is modified so the browser refreshes it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was the slashes  hahaha , the server is in Linux 
So, they have to be like this  "includes/img/defaultimg.jpg?="
instead of "includes\img\defaultimg.jpg?="
LOL